# List all inner classes of a given class - Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

Given a class, how would I list all of its **inner** classes?

```
class Car:
    some_var = "var"

    class Engine:
        some_other_var = "var2"

    class Body:
        another_var = "var3"
```

Now given `Car`  I want to be able to list or iterate over all of its inner classes (`Engine`, `Body`)

(Python 3.5)

Comment: Car.__dict__ should give you a starting point

Comment: What version of Python are you using?

Comment: Why do you want to define these classes inside `Car`? It's _possible_ to do that in Python, but rarely desirable. And you probably should be using instance attributes for those variables, not class attributes. You _can_ use class objects directly to store data like that, but the usual practice is to create instances of your classes.

Comment: `[c for c in vars(Car).values() if isinstance(c, type(Car))]`

Comment: @PM2Ring its a config file, it stores strings and I want the to have and ordered manner.

Comment: @jpmc26 python3.5

Comment: You're using a .py file to store config data? There's probably a better way to do that...

Comment: @PM2Ring I was looking to user `configparser` but it does not support nesting, which is important to me. Do you have any other suggestions?

Comment: You could use JSON. See [here](https://gist.github.com/PM2Ring/8e819c4b6b1b27a3588567c9c0aa5f34) for a couple of options. Python's [`json`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html#module-json) module makes it very easy to read & write JSON data. Another option is XML, but that's more tedious to process, and JSON is a lot easier for humans to read (and modify manually) than XML.

Comment: Also, for less verbosity than JSON (typing all the {, ", ","s ) you may take a look at YAML.

But for sure, using nested classes just to store configuration is not a good approach.

Comment: for what reason using classes as config files are bad?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do something like this:

```
import inspect
[d for d in dir(Car) if inspect.isclass(getattr(Car, d))]
```

It will give you a list of Class in your class `Car`.

Be mindful, variable `d` is a string

Comment: This also returns `__class__`.
Should add `and d !=  '__class__'` I guess